Appwrite doesnt get user in NEXT project
I have this Get User function in lib/actions/user.actions.ts:
export const getUser = async (userId: string) => {
  try {
    const user = await users.get(userId);

    return parseStringify(user);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Message:", error.message);
  }
};

If I console.log before the user.await the userId is correct, and exists on the db
Anything after that first line on the try doesnt work, because the user.get moves directly to the catch
The console is printing this error:
Message: Unexpected token '/', "// File: /"... is not valid JSON
My appwrite.config looks like this:
import * as sdk from 'node-appwrite';

export const {
    PROJECT_ID, 
    API_KEY, 
    DATABASE_ID, 
    USERS_COLLECTION_ID,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET_ID: BUCKET_ID,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT: ENDPOINT
} = process.env;

const client = new sdk.Client();

client
    .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT!)
    .setProject(PROJECT_ID!)
    .setKey(API_KEY!);

export const databases = new sdk.Databases(client);
export const storage = new sdk.Storage(client);
export const messaging = new sdk.Messaging(client);
export const users = new sdk.Users(client);


I've tried with Postman,
url: https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/users/66e4946b0008ac254338
answer:
{
"$id": "66e4946b0008ac254338",
"$createdAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.549+00:00",
"$updatedAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.549+00:00",
"name": "Stephanie Rubio",
"password": null,
"hash": "argon2",
"hashOptions": {
"type": "argon2",
"memoryCost": 2048,
"timeCost": 4,
"threads": 3
},
"registration": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.547+00:00",
"status": true,
"labels": [],
"passwordUpdate": "",
"email": "test@email.com",
"phone": "+526561233466",
"emailVerification": false,
"phoneVerification": false,
"mfa": false,
"prefs": {},
"targets": [
{
"$id": "66e4946b919a9ab13f5b",
"$createdAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.596+00:00",
"$updatedAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.596+00:00",
"name": "",
"userId": "66e4946b0008ac254338",
"providerId": null,
"providerType": "email",
"identifier": "test@email.com"
},
{
"$id": "66e4946b95c2928a09f6",
"$createdAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.613+00:00",
"$updatedAt": "2024-09-13T19:37:15.613+00:00",
"name": "",
"userId": "66e4946b0008ac254338",
"providerId": null,
"providerType": "sms",
"identifier": "+526561233466"
}
],
"accessedAt": ""
}
I dont know what I'm doing wrong, what to check
